# My program keep outputting my function as <function calculate_Q at 0x000002016E2BC280> instead of the value calculated by Q=(V*A)

Tags: python

```
    channel_type= input('Enter the Channel Type: ')
        b= input('Enter a value for b: ')
        y= input('Enter a value for y: ')
        
        
        #now based on the type of channel, calculate A, P, B, R and Dm.
        #in case of a trapezoid channel, take x = 3.
        def calculate_APBRDm(channel_type, b, y):
            if channel_type == 'rectangle':
                A == (b*y)
                P == (b+(2*y))
                B == b
                R == ((b*y)/(b+(2*y)))
                Dm == (y)
                
            if channel_type == 'trapezoid':
                x == 3
                A == ((b+(x*y))*y)
                Z == math.sqrt(1+(x*x))
                P == (b+((2*y)*Z))
                B == b + 2*x*y
                R == (((b*(x*y))*y)/((b+(2*x*y))(Z)))
                Dm == ((b+(x*y))*y)/(b+2*x*y)
        
        #after calculating all parameters, calculate the average flow velocity.
        n = 0.03
        s = 0.002
        
        def calculate_V(n, A, P, s): 
            V= (1/n)*(A/P)**(2/3)*s**(1/2)
        #finally, your code should calculate the discharge of the channel
        def calculate_Q(V,A):
            Q=(V*A)
            
        print ("\nThe Value of the Discharge of the Channel", calculate_Q)
        
        
        
        
        #your code should then print the velocity discharge of the channel, rounded to the 2nd decimal.
        #your print statement should clearly state what each variable is, not just print out raw numbers.
```

When I run my function and input my values, the code prints:

The Value of the Discharge of the Channel <function calculate_Q at 0x000002016E2BC280>

How can get this program to output the value for Q where it says "function calculate_Q at 0x000002016E2BC280"? I attempted to print Q instead, but the code says that "NameError: name 'Q' is not defined".

Comment: You should _call_ the function.

Comment: Welcome to SO Riley! [The same code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67128269/any-idea-why-v-is-an-undefined-number-i-am-getting-a-zerodivisionerror) was posted here two days ago. Is there an email list or office hours for this class? It might be better to work with course collaborators instead of random internet strangers.

Comment: As tkausl said, just replace ```print ("\nThe Value of the Discharge of the Channel", calculate_Q)``` with ```print ("\nThe Value of the Discharge of the Channel", calculate_Q())```

Comment: @jonas I tried replacing them as you showed, but it then I get a type error: "TypeError: calculate_Q() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'V' and 'A'". However, when I add V and A to the call function, it then says V is not defined.

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes there are office hours, and I also emailed my teacher but figuring as it is a Sunday evening I wasn't sure when or if my teacher would respond today. Figured the larger the net I cast the more likely I am to get help.

Comment: That is because, V is nowhere defined. It's only defined in the functions ```calculate_V ``` and ``` calculate_Q ```. You either have to call ``` calculate_Q() ``` from ``` calculate_V ``` get V first by writing: ``` V = calculate_V(n,A,P,s) ```and then call the function (but you need the args for the ```calculate_V ```function.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing inside the function.

```
def calculate_Q(V,A):
                Q=(V*A)
                Print("Answer = ",Q)
```

And in the last print statement in your code, call the function

```
print ("\nThe Value of the Discharge of the Channel", calculate_Q(add_paramenters_here))
```

Comment: When I try to print within the function, there is no output. Also, when I try to print by calling the function, I used the parameters V&A (as those are the parameters used in Calculate_Q) however I get "NameError: name 'V' is not defined". Is there any other way you know of, or something might have done wrong? Also, when I leave out V&A from the call to function, it says I am missing V and A, but when I put V and A in it says they're undefined.

Comment: @RileyPeterson try calling the function with constant values, for example 'calculate_Q(2,3)' and 'print(Q)' in the function body. In main just call the function instead of a print statement. This will verify if there is something wrong with how you're calling the function or if there is something wrong with the function itself.

Comment: @RileyPeterson you're not getting output because you're never calling the function.  To call the function you need to put parentheses after it: `calculate_Q()`.